# Override cache directory in config.yml

Tags: php, symfony

Am I able to override the cache directory from config.yml or parameters.yml?  Or set a config var and use this in AppKernel.php?

I've read, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-cache-dir

However having the config for an app in one place is a better idea, config.yml.  In the example AppKernel needs to be modified to change the dir.

I could override something like this,

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return $this->config->cacheDir;
}
```

Comment: I believe It depends on how you are going to use it. If you are using the cache folder for your entire application, yes you can keep it at one spot (Config.xml). The point on the link you've posted is that for good practices you should split the data into different env's folders. In the end of the day, it's totally up to you. And, of course, keep some documentation. =)

Comment: How can i set it in config.xml?  You can't set kernel parameters directly.  You must overload the functions getCacheDir and getLogDir.  Which ive done.  I want those directorys to be configurable in config.yml and used in the getCacheDir function.

Comment: Since the current cache dir is coded like this $this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment; The only thing you can do is overwrite the getCacheDir Method and return a config variable, as you already figured out in your question.

Comment: $this->config doesn't exist, i was just giving an example.